# Knit html in Macbook Pro M1 Max

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to knit markdown to html and pdf but got error message.

sh:

```
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable
Error in strsplit(info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc' --version' had status 126
Execution halted
```

I tried to download Pandoc, Latex, or Tinytex but didn't work.

Comment: You should reinstall RStudio, which includes Pandoc.  Make sure you get a version that matches your hardware.